# Array of pointer to function

Tags: c, pointers

Is there any  difference between an array of pointer to function and an array of function pointers in c. please give an example of each

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array of pointers to functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628814/array-of-pointers-to-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as a function pointer is a pointer to a function.

```
typedef int (*Pf)(int); /* This defines a type to hold the addrese of int foo(int). */
Pf pfs[42]; /* Declares an array of the above. */
```

A possible reason for possible irritation is that

```
pfs[0] = foo;
```

and

```
pfs[1] = &foo;
```

result in the same value for `pfs[0]` and `pfs[1]`.

Comment: How can I specify the return type of a function that returns an array of function pointers? how can I go about this? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @Rika: This is worth a separate question.